# putting conditions to my presentation controller from retrieved data firebase

Tags: ios, swift

im using presentation controller and i want it to appear only if the area name is (king saud university) or (king khalid airport) and the (isAvailable == true ) and the value of sensor is true.
im using different values for each area so i assign them with 1 or 2. attached is a screen shot of my firebase and my code. what do you suggest so i can solve the problem [sensors database][1]?
[areas database][2]

````
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfirmAndPay")
                            
                            if let presentationController = viewController.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
                                presentationController.detents = [.medium()] /// change to [.medium(), .large()] for a half and full screen sheet
                            }
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("Areas").observeSingleEvent(of:
               .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

              let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let isAvailable = value?["isAvailable"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let areaname = value?["areaname"] as? String ?? ""
                print(isAvailable)
                print(areaname)
            
            ref.child("Sensors").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [self] (snapshot) in

              let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
              let Value1 = value?["Value1"] as? Double ?? 0.0
              let Value2 = value?["Value"] as? Double ?? 0.0
            
                if  areaname == "King Saud University" && isAvailable == 1 && Value1 == 1  {
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
                } else if areaname == "King Khalid Airport" && isAvailable == 1 && Value2 == 1  {
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
                }else if isAvailable == 0 {
                    let cell = self.ParkingsViews.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
                    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                    cell.Alert.text = "No Available Parkings"
                }
            
                
            })})
        } ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqcHR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz3VS.png
````

Comment: No images have been attached to your post and I suggest you remove your earlier post which is asking the exact same question and please attach your images properly.

Comment: its attached at the end of the code

Comment: Apologies, did not notice that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse for a key called `isAvailable`

`let isAvailable = value?["isAvailable"] as? Double ?? 0.0`

But your key is **not** `isAvailable`, it is `isAvailable1` and `isAvailable2`

[image: Firebase Swift iOS parsing]

Make sure you are checking for the right keys. Because of this your `if` conditions are always false and no view controllers get presented.

As I mentioned earlier in the comments, the way to debug these kinds of issues is to add `breakpoints` in your `if / else` blocks to check which path your code goes into and figure out why it is not going into your desired path.

Here is how to add [breakpoints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-breakpoints-to-pause-your-running-app)